# Is the identify pearl material component consumed after each casting, or is it reusable?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, balance

Identify spell reads:

> Components: V, S, M (a pearl worth at least 100 gp and an owl feather)

Is that pearl consumed? Or is it reusable?

[This article](http://projectmultiplexer.com/2014/09/20/how-the-identify-spell-destroys-the-world/) is written on the assumption that the pearl is consumed.

But the text does not have *"consumes"* in the material components.

Comment: I'm nominating my own question as a dupe. Yay for indexing.